# Dynamic titles with function components

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Recently I started rewriting some of my legacy code that used class components to modern hooks. The issue I have is that I used this to set header title like so:

```js
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: someVar,
})
```

Now, I have to do it like so:

```js
MyScreen.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
        title: navigation.getParam('headerTitle'),
    }
}
```

and then

```js
useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setParams({
    headerTitle: 'Some title',
    })
}, [])
```

Which works fine with static screen titles. But for dynamic titles it does not. It takes a second to update the title, first it renders with empty title. Which is explainable, given the method. It worked perfectly with class components. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the params (`setParams`) passed to the screen and not the options (`setOptions`) of the screen itself which is what's causing the odd behaviour you are experiencing.

I am not sure what your use case is so I can't tell you which one to use but there are two ways to set the title in react navigation. Either from the navigator using the options parameter or from inside the component using `navigation.setOptions` take a look at this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers